# Receiving data as an array from BLECharacteristic on Arduino Nano BLE Sense

Tags: ble, arduino-nano-ble

I'm encountering an issue while working with the Arduino Nano BLE Sense and the nRF Connect app. I am trying to receive data from a BLECharacteristic as an array. However, regardless of the size of the data sent from the nRF Connect app, I consistently get a valueLength of 1.

**Sketch**

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

#define SERVICE_UUID "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"

BLEService watchService(SERVICE_UUID);
BLEByteCharacteristic pCharacteristicTX(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX, BLENotify);
BLEByteCharacteristic pCharacteristicRX(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX, BLEWrite | BLEWriteWithoutResponse);

void onConnect(BLEDevice central)
{
  // central connected event handler
  Serial.print("Connected event, central: ");
  Serial.println(central.address());
}
void onDisconnect(BLEDevice central)
{
  // central connected event handler
  Serial.print("Disconnect event, central: ");
  Serial.println(central.address());
}

void onWrite(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic)
{
  int len = characteristic.valueLength();

  Serial.print("Received Data, len: ");
  Serial.println(len);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(" 0x");
    Serial.print(characteristic.value()[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    ;

  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Starting ble sketch");
  BLE.begin();
  BLE.setLocalName("Nano BLE");

  // Create the BLE server
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(watchService);

  // Set up characteristics
  pCharacteristicRX.setEventHandler(BLEWritten, onWrite);
  // pCharacteristicTX.setEventHandler(BLEWritten, )

  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEConnected, onConnect);
  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEDisconnected, onDisconnect);

  // Start the service
  watchService.addCharacteristic(pCharacteristicTX);
  watchService.addCharacteristic(pCharacteristicRX);
  BLE.addService(watchService);

  // Advertise the service
  BLE.advertise();

  // Additional settings for iPhone connection issues
  BLE.setConnectable(true);
  BLE.setAppearance(0x01); // Generic Watch
}

void loop()
{
  BLE.poll();
}
```

**Data sent with NRF Connect app**

```
0xABCDEF123456
```

**Serial Monitor**

```
Starting ble sketch
Connected event, central: xxxxxx
Received Data, len: 1
 0xAB
```

**Expected**

```
Received Data, len: 6
 0xAB 0xCD 0xEF 0x12 0x34 0x56
```

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post